# What kind of access can we get after signing an application with platform signature?

Tags: android, android-source

I have built a custom ROM and obtained platform key for that build. Now I am creating a system application signed with the platform key.

Now, I want to make the application write some thing in the system/priv-app folder. When I run the application with superuser access in a rooted phone the code works.

But, is such access possible for the application which is signed with platform's key?

I have tried the following :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "MainActivity";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Here");

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /system/priv-app");



        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());


        dataOutputStream.writeBytes("touch /system/priv-app/foo.txt\n");
        dataOutputStream.flush();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, stringBuilder.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "IO Error");
    }

}

}
```

I do not get any output from the runtime in my application, not even an error but the file is not created in the directory.

Is there an implementation error or such an access is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

A system application has system level access. To remount the system partition you need to have root access, So you won't be able to write to the priv-app directory without "external" help.

If you are building your own custom ROM, you can create a Daemon that will run on the lower levels of the Android stack with root access (refer to [Android Booting](http://elinux.org/Android_Booting) for details on how to run your executable Daemon on start up). You can communicate with the Daemon via a local socket and use it to remount the system partition and copy the files you want.

You can refer to the following tutorial that explains how to create a native server that will open a socket and wait for incoming connections:
[Unix Sockets](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html).

Answer (score 0):

THe system folder is mounted as read-only by default.  With root access you can remount it, but I wouldn't suggest running like that for longer than necessary (longer than it takes to install your app in the priv-app folder).  For one thing if its mounted rw and you do a factory reset you'll brick your device (unless you have a recovery partition).

Comment: My question actually is, will I get root access from the application signed with platform key? Can I remount it rw without having to use su command before?